# Random range of items?

Tags: unity

I want to add random function into this script. If boxDestroyed is true, three items pop up. What i need is to give random number of items between 0 to 3.

```
    public GameObject[] items = new GameObject[3];
    public bool boxDestroyed = false;


void LateUpdate () 
{
    if (boxDestroyed == true)
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject item in items)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                //  int amont  = Random.Range(0,3);
                Instantiate(item, position, Quaternion.identity);

            }
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, for each item in the public items list, you want to spawn between 0 to 3 copies of it? (ie. you could spawn up to 9 items total, if you spawn 3 copies of each of the 3 items in the array)

Comment: _for each item in the public items list, you want to spawn between 0 to 3 copies of it?_ Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd integer (max) of Random.Range(min, max) is exclusive, meaning it wont return that number so you need to set it 1 higher.

```
for(int amount = Random.Range(0,4); amount-- > 0; ){
    Instantiate(item, position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

This will loop 0 to 4-1 (AKA 3) times.

Alternatively you can write it as:

```
for(int amount = Random.Range(0,4); amount > 0; --amount){
    Instantiate(item, position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Your code run well. but sometime it gives me more than 4 items ? like seven or six items. ?!!

Comment: You said you wanted to span between 0 to 3 OF EACH item in the list. If you want to spawn 0 to 3 TOTAL that's a different problem.

Comment: Yes. you right. I did something wrong and now fix it.Thank you.